# How to stop closing sections on opening another section in accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using accordion in dynamically created sections

```
if (Model != null)
{
    int index = 1;
    foreach (var offer in Model.GroupBy(tt => tt.Destination))
    {
      <div class="accordion" id="section<%=index %>"><%= offergroupByProperty.Key%><span></span></div>
      <div>... contents.. </div>
      index += 1;
    }
}

$('.accordion').accordion({ defaultOpen: 'section1' });
```

style is -

```
.accordion {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
height: 20px;

border-top: #f0f0f0 1px solid;
background: #416AA3;
font: tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 1em;
}
    .accordion-open {
    background: #dfe8f6;
    color: #15428b;
    font-weight: bold;
}
    .accordion-open span {
        display:block;
        float:right;
        padding:10px;
    }
```

Its working fine. But I want to stop closing the active section on clicking another section. How this can be possible?

Comment: the whole idea of an accordion is that you open one and it closes the others. If you want multiple open then you need multiple accordions each with just 1 content each.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the below code -

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
       defaultOpen: 'section1',
       collapsible: true
});

$('.accordion').unbind('click').click(function () {
       $(this).next().toggle('fast');
});
```